# javascript make clickable row based on value in first cell

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that's been dynamically generated in jquery DataTables from information obtained from a database through Django. I need to make the row a clickable link based on the data in the first cell of the row. I figured going through javascript might be the best way to go for this matter. So far, I've tried the other suggestions on here, but none of them seam to work. I need it to generate this link: `href="/liquors/get/{{ store.StoreID }}/{{ id }}/{{ SPI }}/"` with the {{ id }} replaced with the  value in the first cell of the clicked row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    window.location.href="yourlink"+$(this).find("td:first").text()
});
```

Comment: This only lets me select the top header row. Not the ones generated.

Comment: @RuSs It Works for all rows.

Comment: I tested it. Only the top row is selectable.

Comment: indeed. I still can't seam to get it to work for my generated rows.